# autowired service called from a component giving null pointer when called with new keyword

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a problem where i have to use a arrayblocking queue service and my architecture is like thi:

Controller:

```
@controller---
@Autowired
private AdhocService adhocService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(){
        adhocService.processFile();

}
```

Service:

i have a method from which i am starting new threads to read and write using arrayblocking queue

```
    @service
-----
    public void processFileData(InputStream inputStream, Character delimiter, Character quoteChar,String fileName,String type, String report, String desc)
        {


        try {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            ExecutorService producerPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            ExecutorService consumerPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            producerPool.submit(new AdhocTasks(false, inputStream, delimiter, quoteChar, fileName, type, report, desc));
            consumerPool.submit(new AdhocTasks(true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));    
            producerPool.shutdown();
            consumerPool.shutdown();
```

i have more methods here as well

component:

In the adhoctask file is declared as component:

```
    @Component
    public class AdhocTasks implements Runnable,QueueService {


    @Autowired
    private AdhocService adhocService;


    //CONSTRUCTOR - PARAMETERIZED

    public AdhocTasks(Boolean consumer, InputStream stream, Character delimiter,Character quoteChar,String fileName,String type, String report, String desc) {
        this.isConsumer=consumer;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.delimiter=delimiter;
        this.quoteChar=quoteChar;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.type = type;
        this.report = report;
        this.desc = desc;

    }

@Override
    public void run() {


        if(this.isConsumer) {
            consumeFileData();
        }else {
            readFileData();
        }

    }
```

And i have implementations of consumeFileData and readFileData. Now the issue is when in consumeFileData i call the autowired adhocService.consume() :

but it is not working :
giving me

null pointer as adhocService object is null

can anyoe help

Comment: Spring tries to inject the parameters of your constructor so it tries to find a bean of type Boolean which can't be found.

Comment: yes but if i remove the @autowired in constructor  then it gives me null pointer exception as the dhocservice is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't happen when the method is invoked, the problem happens as soon as the spring startup.

`AdhocTasks` is a spring component. So its constructor is invoked as for any bean.  But since its constructor has parameters, each parameter has to be considered as a dependency, so Spring try to wire them with spring beans.
First problem : most of the parameters will not find candidate beans that match and second problem : you don't want to autowire these parameters.

As workaround, change a little bit your design. 
Don't make `AdhocTasks` a spring bean as you don't want that and instead of injecting the service that it requires, pass it as a parameter when you instantiate that :

```
@Autowired
private AdhocService adhocService;
//..
producerPool.submit(new AdhocTasks(adhocService, false, inputStream, delimiter, quoteChar, fileName, type, report, desc));
```

Comment: but i am calling the submit in adhoc service itself . it wont be good idea to have adhoc service autowire in adhocservice

Comment: see the changed question

Comment: If you create the `AdhocTasks` instances from the adhoc service, that is still simpler : just pass that as `this`

Comment: @GhostCat I am fine. Thanks And you I hope too :) Woo... Thanks for that important information I had missed. That looks terrible enough.  And no fork possible...